# Google drive, CORS and Range header

Tags: web-applications, google-api, cors, google-drive-api

I'm trying to request data from Google drive using it's API. The application I'm working on is a web app, so it's on other domain and I have to use CORS. Google drive according to their documentation API supports CORS.

My app stores big enough files on the Google drive and in most of cases the app don't need the whole file but just a part of that. That's why I'm trying to do partial downloads using 'range' header.

The problem is that Google API responds to my browser preflight request that I cannot use Range header in CORS requests - just Authorization header is allowed:

```
Request header - Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,range
Response header - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
```

After that browser blocks the GET request and the story is over. Obviously this is a bug in the API.

Does anybody knows what I can do in this situation (avoid preflights, ask google to fix that, use some trick) and how to do that?

Comment: This is in fact a bug, and I'm preparing a fix for this on the Google-side. I'll ping here when it is live (it should be about a week or two).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would be just great. I did a kludge - my application uses php proxy to avoid CORS, it's ok for prototype but I doubt it will work in production.

Comment: Hi Monsur, I just checked the issue and that still exists: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization. Is there any hope to see the fix? Thanks.

Comment: I was out of the office last week so didn't make progress on getting this out. I'll update with a better ETA when I know more.

Comment: This should be live now. Can you try it out?

Comment: Hi @monsur, just checked, there's no change:  
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false  
access-control-allow-headers: authorization  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS  
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 09:27:33 GMT  
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Nov 1 2012 16:51:48 (1351813908)  
I'm trying to reach https://doc-08-ag-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/2n..e2/d9dpeuk95f6vnao2jfvqb8vm0gg8nqc3/1352966400000/09284652906019066827/09284652906019066827/0By3sJbVXlVl3bmUyNDRtU0M5bzQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true&key=myApplicationKey&access_token=aToken

Comment: Ah I didn't realize the domain was googleusercontent.com. I assumed by Drive API that the domain was googleapis.com. The fix for this should go live at the end of November. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Ok, I believe this is working now. Can you verify?

Comment: @monsur That's working perfect, thanks a lot. I'm really happy to see that my service is working as it supposed.